# How to position variable number of elements on semi circle

Tags: javascript, css, html, math, geometry

I saw this awesome circle menu
http://creative-punch.net/2014/02/making-animated-radial-menu-css3-javascript/

My math is too bad to modify it to only distribute the items on the upper half of the circle.

Also I'd like to get rid of its relative % positioning and let the items spread out a predefined distance in pixels instead. So no menu bounding box is required anymore.

Comment: would you like to symmetrically distribute them, or just start from one corner?

Comment: Symmetrical, just like the sample but in half ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
dtheta = dist / rad;
num = Math.floor(PI / dtheta);
theta = (PI - num * dtheta) / 2;

for (var i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
   x = center_x + rad * cos(theta);
   y = center_y + rad * sin(theta);
   theta += dtheta;
   //drawelement(elements[i], x, y);
}
```

- `dist`: distance in pixels between menu elements
- `elements`: list of menu elements
- `rad`: radius of circle
- `center_x, center_y`: coordinates of center
- `num`: max number of elements drawable

N.B. the coordinates passed to `drawelement` are those of the *center* of each menu element, not the top left corner.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't quite fit into the layout presented in http://codepen.io/CreativePunch/pen/lAHiu

Comment: @philik oh ok, how so?

Comment: well the original code uses percentage to position the elements in its container.

Comment: @philik you said you didn't want that, and you wanted a fixed no. of pixels